# The odd thing is, comma placement

Tags: commas

“The odd thing is, she has no idea who he is and why she got all of his heritage.”

I would normally identify this first sentence as having a nominal that-clause acting as a subject complement with the “that” omitted. Which is fine, but it would mean it's incorrect to use a comma in that position, but I get the hunch, the inkling that it *is* correct even while the sentence below cannot take a comma no matter what. Am I just plain wrong? Would there be any other real grammatical reason for there to be a difference other than emphasis?

“The odd thing is that she has no idea who he is and why she got all of his heritage.”

Comment: Related: [Is using a comma as a pause correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199471/is-using-a-comma-as-a-pause-correct/199480#199480)

Comment: I'd score it as an introductory adverb clause.

Comment: Related to "What the problem is, is...." It's colliding structures being melded with pauses/commas.

Comment: The comma is a tool to help you express clearly and the reader to understand. Use it judiciously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the comma, the speaker is making a comment about the statement *she has no idea...*  This is similar to using "hopefully" as a sentence adverb as in *Hopefully, he'll come early.* Without the comma we have Odd thing = She has no idea that ..., which is more of a statement equating something to being odd. I see a difference in emphasis: *I find it odd that...* or *Isn't it odd that...?" versus *It's odd that...* With the comma I feel the presence of a speaker; without, it has a more narrative feel.

There is an analogy with cleft sentences, which emphasize a later part of a standard-order sentence by bringing it forward (*You ate my cookies!* -> *Those were my cookies you ate!)*, except here the emphasis is achieved by "detaching" the *odd*, which is already at the beginning. Perhaps pointing out the oddness was a recent decision.

Comment: +1 but why not directly mention "Oddly" instead of "Hopefully"? _Oddly, she has no idea who he is and why she got all of his heritage._

Comment: That is true...

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the comma is used for clarity when the *that* is omitted.

Without the *that* and absent the comma, you effect a [garden-path  sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence), where (in this case) the noun following the linking verb wants to be a nominal subject complement before it gets around to being part of a zero *that*-clause.

For illustration purposes, I will use a different sentence as an example:

> *The odd thing is, this relationship may actually work.*
>  <sub>Source: [*The Washington Post* — Between Kid Quarterback and
> Coach, Something Unexpected Has Come to
> Pass](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/sports/2002/10/10/between-kid-quarterback-and-coach-something-unexpected-has-come-to-pass/847a4748-d7f1-4fb1-b450-21e6f68bb521/)</sub>

Let’s look at this three ways:

> *The odd thing is that this relationship may actually work.*
>
> *The odd thing is this relationship may actually work.*
>
> *The odd thing is, this relationship may actually work.*

The second, garden-path version leads to *The odd thing is this relationship.* — leaving the reader to get back on the trail for the rest of the sentence.

Here are some examples from the Corpus of Contemporary American English. You can see that the comma-less, *that*-less uses are not very common.

> [*the odd thing is
> that*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=99920159)
>
> [*the odd thing is
> ,*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=99920154)
>
> [*the odd thing is
> NOUN*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=99920165)
>
> [*the odd thing is
> the*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=99920168)

Circling back to your own example . . .

Believe it or not, the *The odd thing is she.* is a pretty good set up for a garden path, using — as it “properly” does — the [nominative pronoun in the predicate](https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/how-to-choose-the-proper-pronoun-with-linking-verbs/).

Comment: Do you really think anyone would treat _the odd thing is she_ as a meaningful unit? Even without _that_ or a comma, people would wait for a predicate of _she_. So I don't think it's a "garden-path sentence" per se. Even if it's such a sentence, the fix is to add _that_, not to add a comma, because adding a comma makes the structure a different one.